# Using DEFAULT objects in RULE definitions possible?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have created two `DEFAULT`s as follows:

```
CREATE DEFAULT defaultSystemStartYearMonth AS '199501'
GO 

CREATE DEFAULT defaultSystemEndYearMonth AS '205012'
GO
```

And then tried to use them in a `RULE` as shown below:

```
CREATE RULE ruleYEARMONTH
AS 
@YearMonth BETWEEN dbo.defaultSystemStartYearMonth AND dbo.defaultSystemEndYearMonth
AND (@YearMonth % 100) BETWEEN '1' AND '12'
GO
```

But this failed with this error:

```
    Msg 128, Level 15, State 1, Procedure ruleYEARMONTH, Line 3
    The name "dbo.defaultSystemStartYearMonth" is not permitted in this context. Valid expressions are constants, constant expressions, and (in some contexts) variables. Column names are not permitted.
```

I want to use `DEFAULT`s in defining `RULE`s to create some user-defined data types, so that any change in those `DEFAULT` values would not require any change in all the `RULE`s' or `TYPE`s' definition.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rules are deprecated: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188064.aspx

Instead you should use constraints:

```
Alter table dbo.MyTable
Add constraint CK_MyTable_VerifyYearMonth 
Check ( YearMonth Between 199501 And 200512 And YearMonth % 100 Between 1 and 12 )
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. Actually, I will have many columns with the same constraint to check. So I thought creating a user-defined data type which complies with this constraint would save me from altering each and every column one by one whenever the check condition needs to be changed. By doing so, I would have to change only the rule for that udt. Any idea to do that?

Comment: @shuvo: A `CHECK` constraint is a table level constraint and it can reference  multiple columns from the same table / table type (ex. somebody can write the following constraint: `CHECK (Column1 < Column2)`) and it can't be linked to multiple tables. How often you have to change these "constraints" ? And why you have to change these "constraints" ?

Comment: @Sahlean, yes the constraints will not be changed every now and then, but it is very likely to have change requirements in the valid months' range over time in my case. Thank you so much for warning about the deprecation and for suggesting to use check constraint. I am now working on writing a UDF to have the check and call that UDF in the `CHECK` constraint.

Comment: @shuvo: Do you intent to replace following range limits: `199501` and `200512` with scalar functions calls ?

Comment: @Sahlean, I have posted an answer below with where I ended up in this case. Please review and make your suggestions, if possible.

Comment: @shuvo: I don't think it's a good solution from performance point view. Please read this [blog post](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/alexander_kuznetsov/archive/2009/06/25/scalar-udfs-wrapped-in-check-constraints-are-very-slow-and-may-fail-for-multirow-updates.aspx) wrote by Alexander Kuznetsov. He is the author of [Defensive database programming](http://www.red-gate.com/community/books/defensive-database-programming). Also, you could do some tests (INSERT / UPDATE) and you could compare my solution with your solution.

Comment: @Sahlean, thank you so much for sharing those invaluable links. And also for suggesting me about that performance point. My design is really poorer than yours from that point of view. If I still want to keep the valid month values in table, not hard coded in the constraints condition, will it perform better if I remove the business logic from database and put those in the application layer?

Comment: @shuvo: I believe that if you move this constraint (`CHECK  (([dbo].[fn_ValidYearMonth](...)=1 AND [dbo].[fn_ValidYearMonth](...)=1))`) from DB to application layer the performance for INSERT & UPDATE could be better if you call those scalar functions  just one time and if you insert/update two or more rows using a single INSERT/UPDATE statement. Ideally, those scalar functions will be called just one time, when the application starts without any arguments (ex. an inline table valued function `fn_ValidYearMonthStartAndEnd()` could return both the Start and the End of YearMonth range).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `DEFAULT`s and `RULE`s, I have created a new table and store the default values in that table.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.SystemDefaults
    (
    SystemStart INT NULL,
    SystemEnd   INT NULL
    )
GO
```

Then created three scalar-valued functions as below:

- One to check the validity of a Year-Month value. This function is to be used in `CHECK CONSTRAINT` definitions.

```
CREATE FUNCTION fn_ValidYearMonth(@YearMonth INT)
RETURNS BIT 
AS
BEGIN

    -- Declare the return variable here
    DECLARE @ValidYearMonth AS BIT = 0

    -- Set the return variable to 1
    -- if the specified year-month is in between system start and end months
    -- and the month value is between 1 and 12
    SELECT  @ValidYearMonth = 1
    FROM    SystemDefaults 
    WHERE   @YearMonth BETWEEN SystemStart AND SystemEnd
        AND @YearMonth % 100 BETWEEN 1 AND 12

    -- Return the result of the function
    RETURN  @ValidYearMonth

END
GO
```

- And two to return default Year-Month values. These functions are to be used in `DEFAULT CONSTRAINT` definitions.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_SystemStart]()
RETURNS INT 
AS
BEGIN

    -- Declare the return variable here
    DECLARE @SystemStart INT = '199501'

    -- Get the system start and store it in the return variable
    SELECT @SystemStart = SystemStart FROM SystemDefaults

    -- Return the result of the function
    RETURN @SystemStart

END
GO

CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_SystemEnd]()
RETURNS INT 
AS
BEGIN

    -- Declare the return variable here
    DECLARE @SystemEnd INT = '205012'

    -- Get the system end and store it in the return variable
    SELECT @SystemEnd = SystemEnd FROM SystemDefaults

    -- Return the result of the function
    RETURN @SystemEnd

END
GO
```

Then, the constraints are defined as follows:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Account]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [CK_Account_ValidYearMonths] CHECK  (([dbo].[fn_ValidYearMonth]([EffectiveFrom])=(1) AND [dbo].[fn_ValidYearMonth]([EffectiveTo])=(1)))
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Account] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Account_EffectiveFrom]  DEFAULT ([dbo].[fn_SystemStart]()) FOR [EffectiveFrom]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Account] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Account_EffectiveTo]  DEFAULT ([dbo].[fn_SystemEnd]()) FOR [EffectiveTo]
GO
```

Now, things looked all right at this point until I tried to make some change in the `UDF`s. I failed to alter these functions raising an error with some messages like this function is being referenced elsewhere. So, I have to create two more stored procedures to drop and re-create all the constraints that reference those functions.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_DBWorks_DropAndCreateCheckConstraints] --'fn_ValidYearMonth'
    @FunctionName AS VARCHAR(500)
AS
BEGIN 

    SELECT 

        -- Drop SQL
        'ALTER TABLE [' + S.name + '].[' + T.name + '] DROP CONSTRAINT ' + CN.name + ';',

        -- Create SQL
        'ALTER TABLE [' + S.name + '].[' + T.name + '] WITH CHECK ADD CONSTRAINT [' + CN.name + '] CHECK (' + CN.definition + ');'

    FROM    sys.check_constraints AS CN

    INNER JOIN sys.tables AS T
    ON CN.parent_object_id =  T.object_id

    INNER JOIN sys.schemas AS S
    ON T.schema_id = S.schema_id    

    WHERE   CN.definition LIKE ( '%' + @FunctionName + '%' )

END
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_DBWorks_DropAndCreateDefaultConstraints] --'fn_SystemStart'
    @FunctionName AS VARCHAR(500)
AS
BEGIN 

    SELECT 

        -- Drop SQL
       'ALTER TABLE [' + S.name + '].[' + T.name + '] DROP CONSTRAINT [' + CN.name + '];',

        -- Create SQL
       'ALTER TABLE [' + S.name + '].[' + T.name + '] ADD CONSTRAINT [' + CN.name + '] DEFAULT ' + CN.definition + ' FOR [' + CL.name + '];'

    FROM    sys.default_constraints AS CN

    INNER JOIN sys.columns AS CL    
    ON  CN.parent_object_id = CL.object_id 
        AND CN.parent_column_id = CL.column_id

    INNER JOIN sys.tables AS T  
    ON  T.object_id = CL.object_id

    INNER JOIN sys.schemas AS S 
    ON  T.schema_id = S.schema_id

    WHERE   CN.definition LIKE ( '%' + @FunctionName + '%' )

END
```

These procedures will generate `SQL` command texts to `DROP` and `CREATE` those constraints.

If any of these `UDF`s is to change then I have to follow these steps:

1. Generate the `SQL` command texts to `DROP` and `CREATE` the constraints that reference the function.

2. Copy the command texts into some file for use in steps 3 and 5.

3. Drop the constraints.

4. Make the required changes in the `UDF`.

5. Create the constraints that were dropped in step 3.

This is where I ended up in this case so far. Any suggestion to improvize this solution is very much welcome here.

Comment: As a side note: [`CREATE PROCEDURE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms187926.aspx): "Avoid the use of the **sp_** prefix when naming procedures. This prefix is used by SQL Server to designate system procedures. Using the prefix can cause application code to break if there is a system procedure with the same name."